# Asp.NET Core WebAPI not running in docker container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core

When I try to run my ASP.Net Core web api in a docker container, the application exitst early.
My Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet restore

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /out/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /out/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebService.dll"]
```

But when i try to run this container the only log thats displayed is this

```
2022/08/11 09:11:20.802 | Warn |  | Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository| Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
```

and the container exitst with exit code 139.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The message you show is a warning and is not what's causing your container to exit

Comment: @HansKilian Yes I was thinking that. But any other guesses as to what could be the cause?

Comment: are you doing anything related to dataprotection in your api.? show us that part

Comment: @CodingMytra I have to say I dont actually know where this warning message is coming from. I dont use anything regarding data protection and this message only occurs when starting in the docker container

Comment: are you doing anything related to identityserver in your api ?

Comment: No nothing like that either. I am currently changing the server from Http.Sys to Kestrel as Http.Sys is only supported under windows. maybe thats the issue

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong with your app with just this information. What does the app look like?

Comment: did you find any resolution for this? Im facing a similar issue where the app just crash without any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Th data Protection stores keys in the HOME directory (/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys) so when the container restart the keys will be lost, and it might crash the service.

Add a Volume to

```
root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys
```

To check if the error is something else, please build in the debug mood

```
RUN dotnet publish --output /app/ --configuration Debug
```

Comment: Building the image with --configuration Debug did not change the outcome. Same output. Will try adding the volume next.

Comment: try to use base as mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:6.0-buster-slim

Comment: That image does not exist